# Running NSQ in Docker

Tags: docker, nsq

I am trying to spin up NSQ using `docker-compose`.

```
nsqlookupd:
  image: nsqio/nsqlookupd
  ports:
    - "4160:4160"
    - "4161:4161"

nsqd:
  image: nsqio/nsqd
  ports:
    - "4150"
    - "4151"
  links:
    - nsqlookupd:nsqlookupd
  command: -lookupd-tcp-address=nsqlookupd:4160

nsqadmin:
  image: nsqio/nsqadmin
  ports:
    - "4171:4171"
  links:
    - nsqlookupd:nsqlookupd
  command: -lookupd-http-address=nsqlookupd:4161
```

The containers run fine, I can even access the admin panel via web browser, but connecting to nsqd is not possible:

```
~/D/t/nsq % boot2docker ip
192.168.59.103
~/D/t/nsq % curl -d 'hello world 1' 'http://192.168.59.103:4150/put?topic=test'
curl: (7) Failed to connect to 192.168.59.103 port 4150: Connection refused
~/D/t/nsq %
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Two things:
1) the nsqd entry in your compose file should properly expose the ports:
`ports:
    - "4150:4150"
    - "4151:4151"`

2) the port for the HTTP interface is 4151 so try 
`curl -d 'hello world 1' 'http://192.168.59.103:4151/put?topic=test'`

Comment: Did you mean to change the port to **4151** in point (2)?  i.e.: 

`curl -d 'hello world 1' 'http://192.168.59.103:4151/put?topic=test'`

Comment: If I expose the port via "4150:4150", I still get `error connecting to nsqd - dial tcp 192.168.59.103:4150: connection refused`

Comment: I think @21Zoo was suggesting you try to connect to port 4151, instead of 4150.

Comment: Ah yes, let me edit this, the curl should try to connect to port 4151.

Comment: Thanks, it works now :) My macbook BSOD'd, so I forgot to reply here.

Comment: I tried to curl with `curl -d 'hello world 1' 'http://172.20.0.3:4151/put?topic=test'` and get response: *{"message":"NOT_FOUND"}*, what does it mean?

Comment: oh, sorry, the correct API endpoint for the current nsqd version is /pub not /put.